# Unable to run an Android App develoepd in 2.2 to 4.0 version

Tags: android, json

I am a beginner in Android, this is my first app in Android and I stuck very badly, I need your kind help.

Here is  the problem statement.

> We have a very huge database in MySQL, I need to do authorization with
>   an android app and on successful log in i need to display all the
>   order details of that logged in user.

So to do this I have used PHP for the backend work like, authorisation, displaying the order for that user and updating. Unknowingly I worked with ANdroid 2.2(Floryo) version. All these functionalists are working fine with Android 2.2 version but when I try to run the same with Android 4.0 then it giving me runtime error. I am getting the response in terms of JSON from a PHP script file.

What is missing in this case. Do I need to install any library.

Please help me out. After getting the work done also I am unable to show my work.

Comment: post the block of code with error which you are getting

Comment: my guess is that you're falling on RunningOnUIThread

Comment: Better you post your error details so that other can know what is your exact issue.I guess you are calling your webservice on Main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check with SQl problem first, i think sqlite version is different in Android2.2 and Android4.0, some queries work differently in this, I know my answer to your question is half.

Comment: No where I am using Sqlite in this case. I am sending a request to a PHP file and there it is showing me this error.
"connection to 10.0.2.2 failed" this error I am getting in the LogCat.

Comment: I am able to run the same source code if I run it on AVD 2.2, if I change the AVD by 4.0.3 then this error occurs.